# How can I texture a cubed sphere using noise in Three.js so that all six sides are continuous?

Tags: canvas, three.js, textures, noise

I'm working on a project where I need to texture a cubed sphere using noise in Three.js, so that the texture is continuous across all six sides. I've already created the cube using six planes for each side, but I'm having trouble getting the noise to be continuous across the cubed sphere.

Can anyone provide some guidance on how to texture a cubed sphere using noise in Three.js, so that the texture is continuous across all six sides?

WORKING EXAMPLE: [CUBED-SPHERE-NOISE](https://codepen.io/miguel007/pen/JjmEOew?editors=0111)

Here is the cube with noise:

[image]

Here is the cube transformed into a sphere (as you can see the noise isn't continuous between each side):

[image]

Here is an image of what I want the outcome to look like:

[image]

this is how the cube this created

```
 var front = buildMesh(texture);
    var fg = new THREE.Group(front)
    fg.add(front)
  
    var back = buildMesh(texture);
    var bg = new THREE.Group(back)
    bg.add(back)
    bg.position.z = -w;
    bg.rotation.y=(Math.PI)

    var right = buildMesh(texture);
    var rg = new THREE.Group(right)
    rg.add(right)
    rg.position.z = -((w)/2);
    rg.position.x =  ((w)/2);
    rg.rotation.y = (Math.PI/2)


    var left = buildMesh(texture);
    var lg = new THREE.Group(left)
    lg.add(left)
    lg.position.z = -((w)/2);
    lg.position.x = -((w)/2);
    lg.rotation.y=(-Math.PI/2)

    var top = buildMesh(texture);
    var tg = new THREE.Group(top)
    tg.add(top)
    tg.position.z = -((w)/2);
    tg.position.y = ((w)/2);
    tg.rotation.x=(-Math.PI/2)

    var bot = buildMesh(texture);
    var bog = new THREE.Group(bot)
    bog.add(bot)
    bog.position.z = -((w)/2);
    bog.position.y = -((w)/2);
    bog.rotation.x=(Math.PI/2)

    var g = new THREE.Group()
    g.add(fg)
    g.add(bg)
    g.add(lg)
    g.add(rg)
    g.add(tg)
    g.add(bog)
    
  scene.add(g)

  function buildMesh(t){
    let geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(w, w,50,50);
    uniforms = {u_tex: {value: t },wTl:{value:new THREE.Vector3()},ps:{value:new THREE.Vector3()}}; 
    let material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial({
      uniforms: uniforms,
      fragmentShader: fragmentShader(),
      vertexShader: vertexShader(),
      wireframe:false
    });

    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    return mesh
  }
```

this is how i'm calculating my 'localceter' vertex shader variable to normalize each plane.

```
    var sides = [
      ...fg.children,
      ...bg.children,
      ...rg.children,
      ...lg.children,
      ...tg.children,
      ...bog.children,
    ]

    var cnt = centerPosition(g)
    var localCenter = new THREE.Vector3();
    for (let index = 0; index < sides.length; index++) {
      const element = sides[index];
      element.worldToLocal(localCenter.copy(cnt))
      element.material.uniforms['wTl'].value = localCenter
    }

  function centerPosition(g) {
    bbox.expandByObject(g);
    var center = new THREE.Vector3();
    bbox.getCenter(center);
    return center
  }
```

the fragment and vertex shader

```js
function vertexShader(){
  return `
  varying vec2 vUv;
  uniform vec3 wTl;

 vec3 planeToSphere(vec3 p, vec3 localCenter){
    p = p - localCenter;
    p=normalize(p);
    float length = -length(p);
    p = p * length * (localCenter.z*1.0);
    p = p+localCenter;
    return p;
  }

    
varying vec3 v3n;
    void main() {
      vUv = uv;
      vec3 newPosition   =  planeToSphere(position,wTl) ;
      vec3 worldp = ( modelMatrix * vec4(newPosition,1.0)).xyz;
      float n = snoise(worldp*.04);
      v3n=vec3(n,n,n);
      vec3 finalp = newPosition+normal*n;
      gl_Position = projectionMatrix  * modelViewMatrix * vec4( finalp, 1.0 ) ;
    }
  
  `
}

function fragmentShader(){
  return `
    varying vec2 vUv;
    varying vec3 v3n;

    
    void main() {

      gl_FragColor  = vec4(v3n,1.0);

    }
`
}
```

Comment: The approach you’re using wouldn’t work because a cube’s UV mapping either repeats on each face, or it follows a cross pattern [like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ukE1m.png). A noise generator is naturally random, so closing all those edges seamlessly would be impossible, since those UV positions diverge. I think your best bet is either making the texture manually in Photoshop, or using a  noise generator in the shader with `x, y, z` position as the input instead of UVs. This would give you seamless edges because the positions along these edges would always be adjacent.

Comment: You will need to create spherical projection UVs for your cube, you could just use blender for that. The second part would be creating a seamless noise texture, something like 3d perlin noise would do.

Comment: @Marquizzo I add an example of the problem if you don't mind taking a look.

Comment: @Marquizzo  I have a theory that the rotation of each plane is what causes the noise not to be continuous at the edges. but I don't know how to go about solving that problem.